# Is there any difference in Kotlin between a capped type parameter extension function and a normal extension function?

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, type-parameter

Is there any difference between these two?

```kotlin
fun <T : Parent> T.function() {}
```

vs.

```kotlin
fun Parent.function() {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote it - no.

It is important for function chaining:

```
fun <T : Parent> T.function():T { return this } //allows chaining
```

vs.

```
fun Parent.function():Parent { return this } //casts to base class
```